# install a printer with ubuntu

Tags: gnome

I have to install a printer Hp Deskjet 3524 and I have a Ubuntu system (12.04). The guide gives me information only for Windows and Mac. Which are the steps I have to do to install it

Answer (score 0):

Start the printers dialog from dash and choose "add printer". All the next steps should be fairly easy to follow (and HP has a good track record).

[And it seems ther is an installer](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/deskjet_aio/deskjet_3520_series.html):

[image]

and [here is how you install the driver](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/downloads.html) on Ubuntu =if= 'add printer' does not work.